# Stackbooks from data on Stackoverflow

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow, books

I am a PHP coder and am trying to learn some C++ to develop some toolbars for my website (for IE). While Google is a wonderful resource, SO over the past years has collected a lot of knowledge/info about programming.

So while on the interwebs I will come across C++ beginner tutorials on various C++ websites and introduction to Win32 API on MSDN,articles about COM, hooks and more, I fear that there might be a post/posts on SO about doing what I want to do in an easier manner with plenty of first hand experience with what route of development to take etc. Now these posts should be searchable given I use the right Keywords, but what if I don't know them?

The problem is that the info on SO is spread across numerous questions, with dupes & related questions adding to the mess(and sometimes adding to knowledge). Is there a plan to integrate knowledge spread across questions and bring them together, either through teamwork(ala wikibooks) or through an algorithm?  For eg. a team interested in C++ could take up questions tagged with C++ and come up with a book like layout for the C++ tag
Like:

```
C++
..
--Win32
..
----COM
..
----IE Toolbars
----IE addons
```

With user-edited introductions (wherever possible/needed like tag info) and related questions.

Is stackbooks on the teams mind?

Comment: What happens when, half-way through pre-press, the site suddenly accumulates a slew of new, really good questions and answers? One of the strengths of the web site is that is is a dynamic resource and tends to get better over time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To some extent, tag wiki's already do this. [I know `[java]`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java/info)already does this listing common questions at the bottom, but not all tags do, [eg `[scala]`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/scala/info).

[The `[c++]` tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/c++/info) does contain some questions and external FAQ's you can look at.